# Paragraph mark of UWP RichEditBox is not resized

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

With this code (`Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;`) I change the font size of a UWP `RichEditBox` in the `Page_Loaded`-handle. When I start typing some characters, everything works fine. But when I select the paragraph mark and then type something, this text appears in the wrong font size (10.5).

What I've tried is to expand the selection before setting the font size, but it seems that there is no paragraph mark when there's no text. But when the rich edit box is empty and I press `Shift+Right Arrow ⟶` (as I would normally select the paragraph mark), the font size is set back to 10.5.

Is there any workaround to prevent that the font size is set back to 10.5 in any case?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="FontSizeBlock" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    <RichEditBox x:Name="Editor" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="HandleRichEditBox_SelectionChanged"></RichEditBox>
</Grid>


public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += Page_Loaded;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Editor.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, 1);
        Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;
    }

    private void HandleRichEditBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        FontSizeBlock.Text = "FontSize: " + Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain  *when I select the paragraph mark and then type something*, I could not reproduce your issue with above description.

Comment: I have added a GIF to explain my issue. Please note that this doesn't seem to happen when I already had typed something and deleted this text before entering new characters.

Comment: Could you try the following code ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me, but I found my own solution to my problem, which seems a bit less hackier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When further investigating my problem, I noted that my issue doesn't occur when there has already been some text in the `RichEditBox` which was deleted.

Therefore, I have tried to programmatically append, select and remove characters in the `Page_Loaded`-handle, and this approach worked for me.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // set any character
    Editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "a");
    Editor.Document.Selection.Expand(Windows.UI.Text.TextRangeUnit.Paragraph);
    Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;
    Editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any workaround to prevent that the font size is set back to 10.5 in any case?

For your requirement, you could force font size to 20 when you  press `Shift+Right`. Please refer the following code.

```
private void HandleRichEditBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FontSizeBlock.Text = "FontSize: " + Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size;
    if (Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size == 10.5)
    {
        Editor.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, 1);
        Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;
    }
}
```