# Clear undo history of UWP RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

Is there any possibiltiy to clear the undo stack of a UWP `RichEditBox`, because I found no property or method to accomplish this?

What I've tried is to set the document text with `Document.LoadFromStream` instead of `Document.SetText`, but the problem is that I need the `SetText` method as a workaround for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128943/paragraph-mark-of-uwp-richeditbox-is-not-resized?noredirect=1#comment109912384_62128943) problem. Therefore, I need a possibility to clear the undo stack afterwards, without modifying the document's text.

Another approach, which didn't work, was to set `Document.UndoLimit` to 0 and then restore back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft said they add the method `ClearUndoRedoHistory()` since 17763, refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.richedittextdocument?view=winrt-19041#remarks).
But I tried, this method does not exist. Only god knows they added.
[image]

=====Update======

As Roy Li - MSFT said, Use the code below.
[image]

Comment: Please try `RichEditBox.TextDocument.ClearUndoRedoHistory();`. This method belongs to `RichEditTextDocument`